# Automate the execution of a Power Shell script which connect to `Connect-ExchangeOnline`

Tags: powershell, office365, exchangewebservices

```
    $EndDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j + 1)
    $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -ResultSize 5000
    $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
    $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
    Write-Host $StartDate `t $Audit.Count
  }
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

now we can manually copy/paste the script inside Windows Power Shell windows >> login to our tenant for MFA >> and run the script.

but my question, is how we can automate the execution of this Power Shell to run daily on the background? in other words how we can login to ExchnageOnline without human interaction?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered turning off MFA for the ExchangeOnline account and using only 1-factor authentication with protected credentials fetching? Imo that would make things easier, otherwise, there is a need to use certificates.

Answer (score 0):

For Connect-ExchangeOnline look at using certificate authentication see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps